# Running MPD server with Mopidy docker container, how do I play on Mac?

Tags: macos, audio, docker, mpd

I'm running the Docker container [stilllman/mopidy](https://hub.docker.com/r/stilllman/mopidy). I can access the Mopidy UI at `http://localhost:6680` and can also control the music that is playing after installing `mpc` with homebrew. However, I cannot figure out how to hear the music that is playing. The container acknowledges the new MPD connection when I try to use the `mpc` command on my local mac terminal. I reach the same situation with Theremin (can control music but not hear).

Answer (score 0):

I was successful by installing pulseaudio via homebrew on my Mac host and connecting my Docker container to it:

```
docker run -it -e PULSE_SERVER=docker.for.mac.localhost \
    -v ~/.config/pulse:/home/pulseaudio/.config/pulse \
    --entrypoint speaker-test \
    --rm jess/pulseaudio -c 2 -l 1 -t wav
```

You could build a similar container running Mopidy and change output to pulse server output (should be in the documentation how to do it).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to using the brittle audio routing through Pulseaudio would be to use the Icecast output of Mopidy: https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/audio/#streaming-through-icecast

Once you setup the Icecast stream, on your host, you could use a browser or MPV to play the stream generated by Icecast.